# Form validations to display in which field of the form user has entered duplicate data

Tags: python, html, database, forms, validation

```
def add_users():
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']  
        email = request.form['email']
        site_url = request.form['site_url']
        user = User.query.get(username)
        print user
        usr = User.query.get(email)
        print usr
        use = User.query.get(site_url)
        print use
         if user:
             flash('Duplicate Username detected')
         if usr:
             flash('Duplicate Email detected')
         if use:
             flash('Duplicate URL site detected')
        try:
            site = User(username,password,email,site_url,'')
            db.session.add(site)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('User Successfully added')
        except TypeError:
            pass
        except IntegrityError:
            db.session.rollback()
            flash('Duplicate entry detected')
    return render_template("add_users.html")
```

I have written a python code to add users in a database. It will detect if there is a duplicate data detected it will rollback the database. Suppose, if I want to know in which form of the field the user has entered duplicate data. This code is not able to fetch the data from form to query it with the existing users. When I print the field where I'm trying to get the form field data, it is displaying none. It is unable to fetch data from the form. I want to be able to display in which field of the form has user entered the duplicate data and to display showing that in this field you have entered duplicate data.Could anyone help me with this?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

P.S This is my HTML code for from.

```
<div class= "content" style="z-index: 1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="wrapper col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <form action="/auth/add_users" method="post" name="Add_Form">       
                <h3 class="text-center">Add User</h3>
                <hr>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h4> Username </h4>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control Email/Username" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username" required="true" autofocus="" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h4> Password </h4>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control Password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password" required="true"/>            
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h4> Email </h4>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control Email/Username" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email" required="true" autofocus="" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h4> Site_url </h4>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control site_url" name="site_url" id="site_url" placeholder="site_url" required="true" autofocus="" />
                </div>
                <div class="buttonalign">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" name="Submit" value="Submit" type="Submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>  
            </form>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What framework are you using for this - is it Flask? You probably want to use a forms validation library, such as WTForms - there is a [Flask plugin](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: I am validating without wtforms, my query is how can I get the data stored in the form by user and query it through the database and display whether this  data is a duplicate or not.